# The reputation tab shows that I have earned the [c] tag badge two times

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges, achievements-dialog

I got the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag badge a few days ago.I had noticed it in my Reputation and Achievements tab some days ago. Now when I checked it, I saw that it had appeared again:

[image: My reputation tab]

Both of them, when clicked, redirect me to the badges tab in my profile page. I checked the activity tab and found out that I've earned that badge just once and that too just 9 hours ago.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tag badges can be *taken away*. If an answer is deleted or downvoted, you could drop below the threshold and lose the badge if you now have fewer than 20 qualifying answers or your total score for the tag dropped below 100 again.

You gained the badge, lost it, then gained it again.

When you lose a tag badge, it is removed from your activity log as well, which is why you see the badge only once there. The system notifies you of *achievements*; losing a badge is not an achievement, so you do not get notified. The tooltip on the box tells you it only shows things you earned, after all.

In your case, the timeline is:

- On November 29th, the upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204475/c-programming-loops-need-explanation-please/27204526#27204526) put you at a score of 100 on [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).
- You gained the badge early on November 30th as the tag scores are updated once a day.
- The same day, the downvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214624/displaying-n-most-frequencies-numbers/27214882#27214882) dropped your score back down to 99.
- You lost the badge again on December 1st when the tag scores were updated again.
- On December 2nd, you got 3 upvotes and a downvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248832/loop-in-system-call-c-program/27249334#27249334), as well as an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246755/c-function-by-open-a-file-and-transfer-the-data/27248173#27248173), putting your tag score up to 102
- Early this morning, December 3rd, you got 2 upvotes for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262392/using-isalpha-leads-to-text-dump/27262576#27262576), increasing your score to 104.
- The tag score script ran again, and awarded you the badge since you qualify again.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. But I think that there should be another feature that notifies a user once he loses a badge.

Comment: @CoolGuy: the system notifies you of *achievements*; losing a badge is not an achievement.

Comment: But getting voted down is one? ;)

Comment: @Theolodis: the system feels you 'earned' the downvote! :-P But note that the green counter at the top *doesn't update* when you are downvoted. Only when you receive a positive reputation change after that is the total updated.