# Why isn't negative reputation shown in the reputation tab at the top?

Tags: discussion, reputation, top-bar

If I get positive reputation, because someone accepts or upvotes one of my answers, then I get a notification from the reputation tab by a green colored icon. But, why isn't negative reputation indicated this way?

[image: Reputation tab]

Sometimes, I wouldn't know about my reputation change(s). Only if I click on the above icon, I will become aware of all of my reputation change(s).

It affects situations like: Someone downvoted my question or answer and I don't know about it. So, I can't improve my question or answer.

Is there any reason why the reputation tab doesn't show negative reputation?

Comment: Because it's called "achievement", and getting downvote is not one of them (I believe there's a dupe for this, but currently I'm on mobile, it's hard to search for dupe)

Comment: I search but didn't found any good answer.

Comment: One positive aspect of this is that I am more "generous" in giving out my downvotes. Though as you said, it is quite annoying when you don't know whether your post is well-received/should be improved.

Comment: This has been asked and proposed many times; SE UX philosophy says that you should only alert users of positive things.

Answer (score 5):

> Some one downvote to my question or answer then i don't know about it.

Downvotes show up if you drop it down. It will either show as a `-2` or for example a `+8` if you got an upvote and downvote on the same post.

I can't say I've ever not known about a downvote.

It would be nice if the drop-down separated gains and losses on individual posts so they could be more clearly seen, but frankly I would prefer that the icon did not turn red or something like that.

Comment: Is there any other reason for that to not showing as positive reputation?

Comment: I don't personally know the answer to *why*. I would just be guessing.

Comment: I feel like I remember reading something along the lines of "by design notifications only alert you to positive events".  You'll still see the entire breakdown (including rep loss) in the notifications, but you'll only be alerted for positive things.

Comment: @ryanyuyu , Similar comment [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278332/the-reputation-tab-shows-that-i-have-earned-the-c-tag-badge-two-times#comment124142_278333)

Comment: *"I can't say I've ever not known about a downvote."* - almost by definition, you don't actually know that this is true.

Comment: @MarkAmery - It can be (vacuously) true.  If Radiodef has ever received a downvote that they have yet to learn of, it follows that they have no evidence that they have been downvoted without finding out.

Comment: @MarkAmery Yes, the statement isn't literally true and I'm aware of that.