# Reputation losses hide future gains in the top-bar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, top-bar

I have been notified of a +5 reputation change.

At first I thought a question of mine had been upvoted. But when I expanded the list, I saw this:

[image]

Initially I didn't understand it, and thought it was a bug. But it has an explanation:

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30278743/1529630) of mine was accepted at 17:37
- I was notified of the `+15` change, and clicked it, so it was cleared.
- However, the post was unaccepted at 17:45.
- I was not notified of the `-15` change (see [Why doesn't negative reputation show in reputation tab at the top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289861/1529630)).
- I received an upvote for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248209/1529630) at 18:46
- The reputation change was then `-15+10 = -5 < 0`, so I wasn't notified.
- I received an upvote for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280547/1529630) at 20:44
- Now the reputation change was `-15+10+10 = +5 > 0`, so I was finally notified.

But this is so confusing. Please change it.

Some ideas:

- Notify reputation losses
- Display reputation losses when expanding the list
- Notify reputation gains, even if there are unnotified reputation losses

Comment: For the third option: Though not if they are from opposite actions (upvote/unupvote downvote/undownvote accept/unaccept) on the same post. Fold those anyway.

Comment: IMHO option #2 is best. That is, the net change displayed on the bar should be the sum of the _displayed_ changes in the list. Hence all changes, up or down, should be displayed. I do agree with commenter Deduplicator that unnotified balancing changes should the folded out of the list.

Comment: I prefer #1, which IMO is the simplest and more intuitive. #2 is also OK because it removes the confusion, but it still prevents being notified of gains after a loss. #3 may still be a bit confusing, is less simple and needs refinement, as Deduplicator [said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294486/1529630#comment194587_294486).

Comment: Closely related: [New rep indicator stops when having negative score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209021) and [Ignore the rep change caused by placing bounties in the achievements reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209467) See also [New top bar can't math](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210139) and especially see the correct solution to this and all related problems at [Make voting activity on your posts available on site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238766/)

Comment: I wish you could just configure what notifications you want. Some people want to be notified of rep losses, some don't. Personally, I don't even want to be notified of rep increases; the "achievements" should only light up when I get a new badge or something. But I understand why not everyone (in fact, probably not most people) wants the same thing as me, and I understand why making everything infinitely configurable is not as good a UX as choosing something sensible, so I'm fine with adding rep losses to the notifications that I already ignore.

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out. I collected screenshots already and was about to ask a similar question.

Comment: I'd love to have it configurable to show losses, a small option somewhere can't be that bad UX-wise.

Comment: @Oriol When you said "please change" it, did you mean you wanted this to be a feature request? You only tagged it as discussion.

Comment: @TylerH If I remember correctly, I first wanted the community to discuss the better option, and then do a feature request. Maybe it would have been better if I posted my ideas as answers and let people vote them separately. Nobody posted an answer but in the comments there was consensus the current situation should be improved, so I'm adding the [feature-request] tag now.

Comment: The dropdown is titled "Achievements".  Doubtful that most SO users consider a reputation loss an actual achievement.  It is designed this way to minimize the number of complaints, the motivation behind most SE choices in the past 4 years.  Nobody ever complains about gaining rep, lots of SO users are unhappy about loss and don't hesitate to send an email or ask a meta question about it.  This question needs a [status-declined] tag, but that causes too many complaints :)

Comment: @HansPassant However, reputation losses are displayed in the expanded list. Not notifying them is inconsistent. And the problem is that a they can prevent notifications of reputation gains.