# Mark rep loss from posting a bounty as "seen" automatically

Tags: feature-request, bounty, achievements-dialog

If you post a bounty, you lose that rep. That is fairly obvious for all users posting a bounty.

However, if you don't check the achievements dialog after you post the bounty, you won't be notified of any changes to your reputation until you've gained more reputation than you lost by posting the bounty (unless you check the achievements dialog manually, or check your profile).

Posting a bounty is something that *you* do.
Any other large negative reputation change is something that is done *to* you.

If a user does something, then they already know that they have done that thing.

[This can be confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313560/4639281), so I propose that reputation lost from posting bounties be automatically marked as "seen" in the achievements dialog to avoid any potential further confusion.

Comment: Thanks! As you said, an edge case, but it did confuse me for a while

Comment: There are many other situations like this, such as new accounts which give +100. I doubt this confuses many people, considering that bounties are not very common with respect to other activities on the site. This doesn't seem significant enough to create a special case for.

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Ignore the rep change caused by placing bounties in the achievements reputation indicator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209467) Closely related here: [Reputation losses hide future gains in the top bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294486)

Comment: @TravisJ the +100 from the association bonus, including the bonus associated with a new account, is reflected in the achievements.  To the best of my knowledge, the bounty rep loss is one of the few rep changes not shown in the achievements.

Comment: @TravisJ this has to do with negative reputation changes only. The only *large* negative reputation changes are posting bounties, corrected voting, or high-scoring posts shown less than 60 days on the site which are deleted. As posting bounties is something that *you* do, and the latter two are things that are done *to you*, I think it is reasonable to make a special case for it. If I post a bounty, I know that I've lost that reputation, why *not* mark it as seen automatically?

Comment: @TravisJ there are 300+ questions with bounties currently on SE. I'm guessing many thousands of people have been affected by this but simply unaware, because once you pass your pre-bounty score again things return to normal. But Josh posted some links which show that it has confused multiple people in the past

Comment: @TinyGiant - That gets back into the original design - which was counter intuitive and broken. Heck, it is still broken. Fixing this one nuance isn't going to make the whole thing suddenly not confusing to users, it will just remove one very small nuance.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Easily fixed? It would require the bounty reputation to not be broadcast only for the creator of the bounty at that time. However, the system automatically broadcast the reputation so this "easy fix" would require an edge case to be inserted into the code. Why not fix a dozen other aspects which are more glaring? Meta voting for example is somewhere that could really use attention if there were a change to be made. But even that isn't getting attention because it is seen by the team as too minor. They have larger projects to tackle than nuance.

Comment: Honestly, it really just looks like you're trolling now, as such I am disengaging.

Comment: See also [my request on M.SE that mentioned this in passing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257395/show-rep-lost-when-downvoting-an-answer-in-achievements-badging).

Comment: @TravisJ I don't think you understand this at all... they don't need to broadcast anything. All they need to do is, after a bounty is created, subtract it from the user's total rep, and set that new total as their new baseline. Then any rep they get after that will give them a notification.

Comment: @andrewtweber Assuming your interpretation is correct, the title of the post is misleading. If I understand correctly, isn't this just a dupe of [Reputation losses hide future gains in the top-bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294486) that Josh mentioned earlier?

Comment: @jpmc26 that question is asking something far more general. This is about a specific use case that is handled badly. No it is not a dupe of that question. It isn't about being notified of the bounty right away, it is about marking that notification as seen in the achievements menu so that it doesn't interfere with further positive notifications because it is something that I did, so I should already know about it.

Comment: That's exactly what the other question is about: you don't get notified of gains after a large loss. As I see it, that's *exactly* the issue you're reporting. The bounty is a large loss. Then you don't get notified about gains (upvotes, accepts, etc.) until the gains exceed the loss. How is this any different? It's just a specific example of the same issue. I'd be *extremely* surprised if it isn't the same code causing the issue. Or am I misunderstanding what you're reporting?

Comment: This isn't just any large loss, it is a large loss that I have knowingly incurred upon myself. It wouldn't make sense for any other large loss, because you don't know about it so sooner or later you're going to to check the achievements menu and find out that your sock-puppet was deleted and you lost all those points. But for an action that I do, I know that I've done that, I've already been notified of the loss. It is unintuitive to have to check the achievements menu to be "notified" of it, when I obviously already know about it. @jpmc26

Comment: @TinyGiant - It is rather dishonest of you to post comments with a lot of vitriol, and then delete them, and accuse me of trolling. This question does not differentiate itself, and stating that this exception is an "easy fix" along with the other comments you removed do not go far enough to make this feature feasible.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it was repeating things I had already said, which I seem to be doing over and over here; it did not contain vitriol, though possibly frustration at having to repeat myself. The proposed duplicate is a general discussion, this is a feature request, they can not be duplicates because they are two different kinds of questions asking two very different things even though they happen to be on a similar subject. @TravisJ

Comment: I think whether you incurred the rep loss or someone else incurred the loss is irrelevant. In my opinion, all changes to reputation should be listed in the achievements/reputation menu, and losses and gains should be separated from each other.

Answer (score 20):

Here is why I think this is a smaller and distinct feature from what's already been discussed.

When you gain rep, your new max is the baseline for getting notifications. If your rep drops below that amount, you don't get a notification for it. This, we already know and have discussed. To me that means that **they must be storing that baseline somewhere already**.

If you have 500 rep to begin with and place a bounty for 100

1. Your rep drops to 400. This is already done.
2. The baseline for notifications stays at 500. So you don't get any more notifications until either:

   - you click on the achievements icon (unintuitive because why click a notification icon when there's no notification?) or
   - your rep goes back above the baseline of 500 (confusing because it could take a long time to get 100 rep back)

I am requesting this simple 3rd step:

3. Update the baseline for notifications to 400. The reason TinyGiant and I think this should be very simple to add is that we are making the **bolded assumption** above. That logic exists somewhere already, so it should hopefully be a simple function call.

With that 3rd step, those 2 bullet points can be eliminated. You immediately start receiving notifications again. Whether this also happens for **other** negative rep changes, I don't really care. But I think bounties are different enough because

1. They are usually a **very large** amount of rep. If you lose rep for a downvoted question, all it takes is one upvote or accepted answer for you to get past your baseline and start receiving notifications again
2. They are a **voluntary** loss of rep. As TinyGiant has said, you know you are losing rep so there is no need to be notified about it.

Comment: "*confusing because it could take a long time to get 100 rep back*" - That depends on who you are :P

Comment: @AshleyMedway I'd guess that earning more than 100 rep in a short timespan after posting a bounty is more an exception than a rule...