# Why is the tag badge count not being recalculated?

Tags: bug, badges, tag-badges

I've noticed a few days ago that I was awarded a silver tag badge twice:

[image]

I don't have any problem with that notification. It seems like a kind of race condition, explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278332/the-reputation-tab-shows-that-i-have-earned-the-c-tag-badge-two-times).

The issue is that the badge count is not recalculated. Even after a few days I still have two silver badges for the same tag ([badge profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614364/bertrand-martel?tab=badges)):

[image]

[image]

I've made a query to get people who have been granted duplicate tag badges (in the current tag badge count) on https://data.stackexchange.com:

Duplicate bronze tags: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1349533/duplicate-bronze-badge

Duplicate silver tags: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1349544/duplicate-silver-badge

For example:

[image]

[image]

So the question:

Why is the tag badge count not being recalculated? Or should it be?

Comment: *"Why tag badge count is not being recalculated ?"* .. I can only guess, but maybe because it doesn't really matter. It is just a cosmetic issue and currently not worth developer time. There are bigger issues to fix.