Why did I earn the same gold tag badge twice?
I just earned the gold java badge twice. I first noticed it in my achievements:

I thought it would just be a fluke of the notification being sent out twice. However, if I check my profile, I see that I really earned the same badge twice, even though that shouldn't be possible according to Which Gold Badges Can be Awarded Multiple Times?.

The page that lists who earned the badge (link), also contains my name twice.
So, why did I earn this badge twice? And is this permanent, or will a cleanup job eventually "fix" this?

Clearly you get the upgraded version of Mjölnir. Congratulations!

The site had some downtime a little while ago, might be caused by that.

See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403839/why-is-the-tag-badge-count-not-being-recalculated

See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63691/duplicated-bronze-tag-badges

Seems that you are the only person that has been deemed truly worthy (or those that were, have since lost their worth): SEDE

@toolic It looks like the person in the first linked post also still has their double [github-api] badge, so I guess I can keep mine for a while as well.

@ThomA Dimitri get to re-dupehammer a question once if it gets reopened after they've initially dupehammered it, I guess :-)

@ThomA the SEDE is only refreshed once per week. Given this award just happened there's no way to know if other users were impacted or not from SEDE.

Gold tag badges are calculated as part of a scheduled task. They're also one of the few badges that can be revoked after having been awarded based on updated tag score values. Given that, I'm going to let this ride a few days because there's a possibility that this issue will resolve itself on the next calculation. If it's still not resolved after that point I'll escalate it.

I'm aware, @HenryEcker , otherwise the OP would be in there. The point is historically no one has 2. The query in the SEDE doesn't filter to today, or any date range, it is all time.

Right, I was just saying that we don't know if they were the "only person deemed worthy" since there could be others impacted since the last SEDE refresh.

@ThomA The group by on Badges.Id makes the query return nothing, if you group by based on B.BadgeName, you get a few results, 3 of them being duplicate gold badges (myself included).

And in all of the cases the BadgeId are consecutive so maybe some sort of race condition or retry? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1872354

My guess is that the badge progress is checked when you visit the website. Maybe I had Stack Overflow open in multiple tabs when I launched my browser, causing the race condition to happen.

I had imagined it would be a scheduled job but doesn't look like it did any other tag badges in that hour so maybe https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1872505
